# Windows 7 Enterprise domain login error

Tags: windows-7, windows-domain, login-screen

So I have this school computer. And I got help from a friend who managed to make the program sethc.exe to become an command promt that you could make pop-up by using sticky keys and from there I created a local admin account off the school domain network. My school computer is hooked up to a domain network and when I would login to my school account(non-admin) I would write
ad.stockholm.se\ab63124 Im from Sweden. Hence the "stockholm" and ".se".
ab63124 is my user name. After that I type in my password which I know is correct. But the problem is that It doesn't work. For example. Before the summer when I was on the login screen. It said what domain I was login on. (ad.stockholm.se) But now, it behaves like a private computer. It's like I can't connect to the school domain server. And the login fields won't allow me to use a domain account. As I write this Im on the local admin account. The folder for my school account still exist C:\Users\ab63124. But I can't accses it.

I need help with this, because I gonna hand this in to my school in approximetly 1,5 years. And if it isn't solved by then.
Well I don't know.

Edit:

So this is how we managed to create an admin account:

First I called the student support and managed to get the BitLocker key for the harddrive. After reciving it. We unscrewed the laptop and took out the harddrive. Then I plugged it into my other computer and unlocked the harddrive with the BitLocker-key. Now we navigated to system32 folder and searched for sethc.exe. When we found it we removed sethc.exe from the folder and replaced it with another program called sethc.exe but it was actully cmd.exe. So when I then put the harddrive back in place and started the school computer and came to the log-in screen. I pressed SHIFT 5 times, and instead of "Sticky Keys" popping up. Now a command prompt popped up. Now we could create a local admin account on the computer. And that's how it went down.

Update: 
I now know what I did. I went into System Properites and in the "Computer Name" tab I clicked on "Change" and unchecked Domain. So it went off the network. However, now I tried to change it to my school domain network, but that didn't work I get errorcode: 0x0000232B RCODE_NAME_ERROR it doesn't find the DNS name of the domain. Does that mean I have to change it while Im at school ?

Comment: What exactly did your friend do with `sethc.exe` and the Command Prompt? It would help to format the post so it's not a giant block of text, it may help get you attention/answers.

Comment: "sethc.exe to become an command promt" that is a hack and a huge security risk.

Comment: Define huge risk please.

Comment: I just want to connect it to the domain network again.

Comment: When the summer started something happend. I did something and suddenly Chrome said CANT_CONNECT_TO_PROXYSERVER everytime I logged onto the internet. And it doesn't recognize the domain name.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a domain-connected computer in an managed-IT environment but not on-topic at Server Fault.

Comment: So you hacked a computer which does not belong to you to add an Admin account? And you expect us to fix it for you when it went wrong?

Comment: Hacked is such a mis-used term. I'd say "tampered with".

Answer (score 0):

Unless your account has privileges to add computers to the domain, you cannot add it back. You could theoretically, and I mean **theoretically**, use some other computers to run a windows server, make THAT domain for your school again and connect the laptop to IT. It's not actually going to ACTUALLY FIX the problem at all, but they will likely think that the domain trust is broken and won't dig too deep into why.

So, what it would look like to them is:

- computer is in their domain, but it's not taking their logins.

  - It might even give a trust relationship is broken error since it's trying to talk to your *fake* domain and the only one it can talk to doesn't have the right info.
- they log in as an local administrator account,
- remove the machine from your fake domain and put it in a workgroup
- Put the computer back into the *real* domain
- computer works like normal. Well, maybe not sticky keys.... but you could probably get this from an unscrewed-with machine and just place it.

---

And here is the more fun way and what I would probably do. First, get anything you'll need off it. We're going to destroy this windows install.

If you aren't willing to make your own fake domain in a closed environment, or it's just way too complicated, then just tear the thing to the ground. Fabulously destroy the windows install. Delete random DLLs from system32. rename things. move stuff. your goal is to get yourself a fantastic bluescreen. Preferably many so that if they fix one there's another waiting behind it. You might want to try a boot disc or live CD so you can get to some files that it won't let you normally mess with.

Once you have it totally screwed up, take it to the helpdesk or whoever and tell them you're not sure what happened. It kind of kept getting slower and slower and then, mention popups and things like browser toolbars. These are the kind of things that inject themselves into stuff and cause problems, but are rarely a real risk. They might struggle with it for a little while, but they're probably just going to restore you from some kind of backup or just re-image the machine.

Just avoid mentioning anything that could be construed as something you ought not to have done. Things like accidentally installing browser toolbars and clicking things you shouldn't have happens all the time, but saying you dropped it and then all this happened would be bad and would likely get you made responsible for it. Software they can easily fix. If they think it's just that it's not really a big deal, if they think it's to do with a physical problem you're more likely to get charged for something.

---

Update: You know? You might could just file a ticket saying something along the lines of: I can't log in to my computer! It says the trust relationship failed!  and they might just remote in and re-connect it. It happens more often than it should even without people screwing with the OS.

Comment: Would you rather get caught, punished, possibly fined, expelled, and potential criminal charges for unauthorized access? Nope. I'd break the hell out of it so they write it off and reimage

Comment: PsychoData is there a way to re-write "I can't LOG IN to my computer! It says the trust relationship failed!" to a more youthful language ? Since Im a High School Student. Like "I can't log in cause it says It can't connect to domain server" ? Is it correct?

Comment: We're connected to Microsoft Lync and you can chat with Student Support. What should I write? PsychoData

Comment: Ummm... Let me break one of our PCs domain trust so I can get the exact wording. Just a couple minutes

Comment: Mkay. If you just took yourself out of the domain and didn't rename your computer, the error would likely be "the trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed" and if you changed the name of the computer at some point, then "The Security database on the server does not have a computer account for this workstation trust relationship". That is the error that would show on screen. And that error would only be showing while you are at school (When you're away from the school network you use something called a roaming profile) Whatever phraseing you like for that error

Comment: When I go into System Properties and click "Change" and then change the checkbox from "Workgroup" to domain, and then enter the domain adress. It pops up and says "Enter the name and password of an account with permission to join the domain". And I enter my school account that of course doesn't have permission. So Im locked out of the domain.

Comment: Yeah, my suspicions above are confirmed that you don't have rights to add computers. You could try the catostrophic failure I suggest above until you get bluescreens, or you can take the semi-honest route and say one of your friends was screwing around with the computer and got it kicked off the domain and now you can't do stuff. No matter what way you go, you're banking on them not noticing OR not caring enough to get you in trouble. Messing around with their computers at my high school (even for way less than you two have done) is In school suspension and at least temporary ban on computers

Comment: While an organisation that hands out Bitlocker keys to users can't really be *that* determined to maintain tight control of their devices, *technically* what you're suggesting is fraud.

Comment: Is it possible for the systemadministrator to notice a local admin account on my computer. If it is. How hard or easy is it to notice ?

Comment: Cicada. Fairly easy. Just run `net localgroup Administrators` to see who is a member of the admin's group. Or open `lusrmgr.msc` and look at the Administrators group for a GUI way. An admin could whipup a script to check if there were extra lines, but I would say that isn't terribly likely unless they have a reason to be looking.